# For loop in an int array only counts first array number in if statements

Tags: java, arrays

So for part of my program I have an int array called testAverages with 21 numbers and I need to loop through the array testAverages and see how many a's b's c's d's and f's there were and then print the total out, but when i run it, it only uses the first array number and says that there were 21 b's and 0 of everything else. Could somebody tell me why it is doing this, any help is appreciated

```
package labs;

import java.util.Arrays;

 class BasicArrays {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] testAverages = {82,79,83,75,86,46,71,73,80,56,82,71,73,78,76,69,58,43,77,65,73}

    int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, f=0;
    // loop through the test averages, and count up the abcdf 's.  
    for (int i =0; i <testAverages.length; i++)
    {
     if (testAverages[i] >= 90)
     {
         a++;
     }
     else if (testAverages[i] < 90 || testAverages[i] >= 80)
     {
         b++;
     }
     else if (testAverages[i] < 80 || testAverages[i] >= 70)
     {
         c++;
     }
     else if (testAverages[i] < 70 || testAverages[i] >= 60)
     {
         d++;
     }
     else if (testAverages[i] < 60)
     {
         f++;
     }
     }
    System.out.println("The amount of a's was: " + a);
    System.out.println("The amount of b's was: " + b);
    System.out.println("The amount of c's was: " + c);
    System.out.println("The amount of d's was: " + d);
    System.out.println("The amount of f's was: " + f);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical bugs. You used `||`, but you want `&&`. Change

```
testAverages[i] < 90 || testAverages[i] >= 80
```

to

```
testAverages[i] < 90 && testAverages[i] >= 80
```

**and** the rest. Consider a 2, it is less than 90. Thus the condition is satisfied, and the second test (because you use **or**) is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

For simpler logic and conditions, I think we can write as follow

```
for (int i =0; i <testAverages.length; i++) {
    if (testAverages[i] >= 90) {
        a++;
    } else if (testAverages[i] >= 80) {
        b++;
    } else if (testAverages[i] >= 70) {
        c++;
    } else if (testAverages[i] >= 60) {
        d++;
    } else if (testAverages[i] < 60) {
     f++;
    }
 }
```

Because `esle` warranty that `testAverages[i]` must be < 90, and so on.